# Raspberry Pi X-session fails to load over SSH

Tags: ssh, linux, xorg, vnc, headless

Am connecting from my Linux (Mint) desktop to the Fedora (rpfr18) Raspberry Pi using SSH X tunneling.
When the Pi comes up, I connect to it from the desktop xterminal using:

> SSH -X root@192.168.x.y

Then I can start any x-window on the remote RPI like

> transmission-gtk &

Q-1) At the moment I'm seeing this error which I don't know how to fix when I issue a:

> /etc/X11/xinit/Xsession

[image]

Don't have the HDMI cable to connect the Pi to my monitor to troubleshoot.

Q-2) I think the above is related to why vncviewer is drawing a window which is completely dark/blank at the moment.

> vncserver #remote rpi
>
> vncviewer 192.168.x.y:z #draws a dark/blank window.

So how do I fix these?

Comment: hmm, the usual programs work fine and the window manager seems to fail?
How are you launching gnome?

Comment: Ah, your comment put me on the right track. I see it is working if I issue a # startxfce4. It wasn't working earlier with #startx or #/etx/X11/xinit/Xsession. Anyways, was strange since I thought Pidora 18 came with xfce4 and not gnome in the first place, but it seems there is something here http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=45586&p=361152
#resolved #thanks

Comment: Sure thing PKM. Pidora is a kewl name, I didn't know that had one for the PI.

Comment: Except if you were Russian :P 
http://www.geekosystem.com/pidora-russian/

Comment: hehe, It looks like a lot of people were amused by that name.